# Read achievements from Xbox Live

Tags: xbox360, xbox

I'm looking for the best way to find out which achievements an Xbox Live username has for a certain game. I'd also like to be able to see secret achievements.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vist https://xboxapi.com to get user information and achievements/games played for a particular gamertag. I am a friend of the site developer, djekl, and he actively maintains the website, constantly providing new features. Here are some examples provided for djekl's unofficial Xbox API: https://github.com/xboxapi/

You can return XML or JSON from the API. You are limited to 350 requests per hour so be sure to cache your results. This is provided as to not overload the server with too many requests.

Here are some example requests that you can make:
djekl's Achievements for Battlefield 4 (1161890234)
https://xboxapi.com/v1/achievements/1161890234/djekl

djekl's Profile:
https://xboxapi.com/v1/profile/djekl

Example of what you can do with the API:
https://xboxapi.com/example/djekl

EDIT:
The v1 endpoints have been discontinued as the v2 API officially supports Xbox One. You can see the new available endpoints here:
https://xboxapi.com/documentation

Note, you will have to login to your Xbox Live account in order to use some features of the API and the API requires an API key.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks! Is the request-per-hour limit based on IP or API key? I plan to use this in an application that I will distribute.

Comment: It's per IP address since the current API allows anonymous access. His beta API will require an API key and will support Xbox One achievements/challenges/games. The current version of the API only supports Xbox 360. If you're going to use this in a mobile app, I'd suggest creating a cache of some sort and only requesting up to the maximum requests per hour.

Answer (score 0):

There are websites you can scrape that have manually entered information regarding lists of achievements, but there is no publically available API you can call to query that information on a per-user or per-title basis.